# Why is my ASM (using Turbo Assembler) program looping infinitely?

Tags: loops, assembly, infinite, tasm

I tried to make a small program which accepts 4 digit number. But for some reason it doesn't stop after entering the 4th digit.

This is the concept I am using.

A four digit number for example 1234 is simply "1000+200+30+4"
So when I enter 1234 in my program this is what happens:

```
1 BX = 0000 0000 0000 0000    

2.1 BX = BX + 1000    

3.1 BX = BX + 100
3.2 BX = BX + 100

4.1 BX = BX + 10
4.2 BX = BX + 10
4.3 BX = BX + 10    

5.1 BX = BX + 1
5.2 BX = BX + 1
5.3 BX = BX + 1
5.4 BX = BX + 1
```

So BX = 0000 0000 0000 1234
But the following program goes into an infinite loop. Can someone help me out with this problem.

```
;===========MACROS==========
;-----INPUT MACROS
INPUT_BCD_SUB MACRO DIGIT
        CALL COMMON_INP_PROC        
        MOV DIGIT_PLACE, DIGIT
        CALL NUM_CONVERTOR
ENDM

INPUT_BCD MACRO VAR
        XOR BX,BX
        SHOW T_MSG2
        INPUT_BCD_SUB 1000
        INPUT_BCD_SUB 0100
        INPUT_BCD_SUB 0010
        INPUT_BCD_SUB 0001
        MOV VAR, BX
        XOR BX,BX
ENDM

;-----SHOW MACRO
SHOW MACRO MSG
        MOV AH, 09H
        LEA DX, MSG
        INT 21H
ENDM
;-----END: SHOW MACRO

;-----KILLME MACRO
KILLME MACRO
        MOV AH, 4CH
        INT 21H
ENDM
;-----END: KILLME MACRO

.MODEL SMALL
.DATA
        T_MSG1 DB 10,13,'Enter a number: $'
        T_MSG2 DB 10,13,'You have entered: $'
        ERR_MSG DB 10,13, 'An error has occured: Invalid digit entered. Please use     digits 0 to 9 $'
        VAR_NUM1 DW 1 DUP(0)
        DIGIT_PLACE DW 1 DUP(0)
.CODE        

    COMMON_INP_PROC PROC
        MOV AH, 01H
        INT 21H
        CMP AL, 30H
            JB  ERR1
        CMP AL, 39H
        JBE SUBT_30
        ERR1: SHOW ERR_MSG
              KILLME
        SUBT_30: SUB AL, 30        
        RET
COMMON_INP_PROC ENDP

NUM_CONVERTOR PROC
        MOV CL,AL
        COUNT: ADD BX, DIGIT_PLACE                   
        LOOP COUNT    
NUM_CONVERTOR ENDP

MAIN PROC
        MOV AX, @DATA
        MOV DS, AX

        SHOW T_MSG1
        INPUT_BCD VAR_NUM1
        KILLME
MAIN ENDP
END MAIN
```

I also generated a list file and it looks fine. I really don't know what the problem is...

[List file generated by TASM](http://pastebin.com/uEU7qytQ)

Comment: Shouldn't `NUM_CONVERTOR` have a `RET` at the end? (I can't remember if `ENDP` inserts one automatically)

Comment: Another potential problem with this code is that you don't seem to clear `CH` prior to using `LOOP` in `NUM_CONVERTOR`. The `LOOP` instruction descrements `CX`, not just the lower 8 bits (`CL`).

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Its midnight here so I'll fix the code tomorrow and will report here. :)

Comment: Also, use a debugger to step through your code and see where it doesn't do what you intended.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, NUM_CONVERTER not having a RET will produce the loop, and CH is never initialised either, both were correct. The advice to single-step is also sound. I'm posting this as answer so you can close this issue so it will no longer show up on the SO site.